# how to submit bulk data to Weblogs ping server

Tags: rss, generator

I am working on news website and I want to publish new news and news updates to weblog using Restful call [WebLogs.com api #7](http://www.weblogs.com/api.html#7)

As time duration b/w calls may not less then 30 mins thats why i want to push bulk updates using RSS aggregator.

I found the following document
http://getaconnect.com/rss/category/queued/
in the format of where item may be multiple

```
<Channel>

<item>
</item>

<item>
</item>

</Channel>
```

Example HTTP GET request to weblog ping server:

http://rpc.weblogs.com/pingSiteForm?name=InfraBlog&url=http%3A%2F%2TestRss.com

My question is if i ping and provide rss file then after 30 mins should i update the same file with new contents to i have to provide separate file.

Another question is if i would like to update text/location of already submitted news how can i do it ?

Last question is any suitable API for rsss generate in java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create rss data and submit it to weblong ping server.